# Spring boot rest api - Best approach to convert getResultList() to Map to display response without creating java class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would need to display stored procedure response(multiple OUT parameters) without creating any java class for that response.

Please anyone explain me how to achieve it. I get getResultList() through stored procedure call, how to parse it and show all data as **"Key" : "Value"** pair.

ResultList may contain multiple cursors or single cursor or single string or multiple string or it could be even combination of cursors and string. I need to parse it all and display it as JSON Object. **Do we have any mapper which does these functionalities automatically?**

**FirstCursor(Returns List of Object):**
[
        {
            "uname": "XYZ",
            "phone": 18653
        },
        {
            "uname": "ABC",
            "phone": 89480
        }
]
**Second Cursor(Returns single object}:**
`{`
 `"uname": "DEF",`
 `"phone": 89489`
`}`
**Third String:**
        "uname" : "IJK"

Comment: What type does `getResultList()` returns? And by parsing you meant to convert that type into a `Map<Object, Object>`?

Comment: It returns List<Object[]>. I must parse it to Map<String, Object>, so that I can return it back as an JSON object(key, value) pair.

Comment: Or is there any other way to display List<Object[]> as an JSON Object("Key" : "Value" pair).

Comment: ...OK, that looks straightforward, but what about the key names? You need to place those details in the question. Give an example input and how would you like that to be outputted. Otherwise it's just a back and forth of people asking for details because we shouldn't infer what do you mean without details. So far it's just mapping a `List` into a `Map`.

Comment: Added. Hope now its clear. Please let me know if you need more detail on it.